# Invalid object name 'Utility.dbo.ProcedureChanges'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a few SQL Server databases, I can create stored procedures in all databases except one of them.

The error I get is

> Invalid object name 'Utility.dbo.ProcedureChanges'

but I don't have any object by that name in my entire database.

Comment: "I don't have any object by that name in my entire database. " - I guess that explains why you get that message.

Comment: The error I get ... when you do what?  You'll have to provide more details in this question for it to be actionable.

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange - What is your suggestion? Should I create a database named Utility and create a schema named dbo and create table named ProcedureChanges? if yes what would be columns of the tables and what sort of data should I put there? Thank you!

Comment: Are you serious? How would I know what you need? Where is that error coming from? Do you have a ddl trigger?

Comment: @JimHorn - Thank you for looking into the problem. The issue is I restored few of the SQL Databases into my system. I can modify store procedure in all databases expect one of them not allowing me to create new procedure or change alter any procedure. The error I get is Ask Question

up vote
0
down vote
favorite
I have a few SQL Server databases, I can create stored procedures in all databases except one of them.

The error I get is

Invalid object name 'Utility.dbo.ProcedureChanges'. I do not have any object by the same name.  Looking for your help. Thank you!

Comment: @SeanLange - in a simple word i can not create a simple procedure on one of my databases. I do not have DDL trigger, The error is Invalid object name 'Utility.dbo.ProcedureChanges' while my query has noting with this object.

Comment: Either your procedure does reference that object or there is a ddl trigger. I can't possibly help you here at this point. There is nothing in the way of details posted here. And if it is your procedure you would get a warning, not an error because of deferred name resolution.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you so much Sean, I appreciate your thoughts. I'll post on this once get a solution. Have a great day ahead.

Comment: @SeanLange  The problem is resolved. I created the database called Utility and created a table as following  USE [Utility]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProcedureChanges](
 [EventType] [text] NULL,
 [EventDDL] [text] NULL,
 [SchemaName] [text] NULL,
 [ObjectName] [text] NULL,
 [DatabaseName] [text] NULL,
 [HostName] [text] NULL,
 [IPAddress] [text] NULL,
 [ProgramName] [text] NULL,
 [LoginName] [text] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: @JimHorn The problem is resolved. I created the database called Utility and created a table as following USE [Utility] GO SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProcedureChanges]( [EventType] [text] NULL, [EventDDL] [text] NULL, [SchemaName] [text] NULL, [ObjectName] [text] NULL, [DatabaseName] [text] NULL, [HostName] [text] NULL, [IPAddress] [text] NULL, [ProgramName] [text] NULL, [LoginName] [text] NULL ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY] GO

Comment: Sounds like you had a ddl trigger? I would be careful using the text datatype. It has been deprecated in favor of varchar(max) for more than a decade now. But glad you solved the issue. The most important though is if you understand WHY it is working now.

Comment: @SeanLange, It works because each time I modify the store procedure a record is inserted int the object named Utility.dbo.ProcedureChanges. I am not expert in SQL therefore don't how and why the audit log is set on the database but I am glad I am able to do my changes for now. Thank you once again for your support.

Comment: Go and research DDL Triggers. That is what is happening.